# string literal combination for colorized readline with string variable

Tags: c, readline

Is it possible to put variable `text_info` to readline among with colors?
GCC debuger gives me this error: `" error: expected ‘)’ before 'text'`

```
#include <readline/readline.h>

#define CYELLOW "\001\e[0;31m\002"
#define RESET   "\001\e[0m\002"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *text_info = "its very simple string";
    readline(CYELLOW text_info RESET);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the way below works but it's not the case.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    readline(CYELLOW "simple string" RESET);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can concatenate constants, but not variables like that. Plus that should be `char* text_info`.

Comment: You could use `sprintf` to build the string, if the `text_info` part is a variable, not a string literal.

Comment: ok, so the only solution is to build the string, right?

Comment: You could use `char *text_info = CYELLOW "it's a very simple string" RESET; readline(text_info);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you posted doesn't work because it can't be combined during build time:

```
readline(CYELLOW text_info RESET);
```

As @Weaterh Vane has already metioned in the comment above, the only real solution is to build the string during runtime via `sprintf` or better `snprintf`.

```
 char aBuffer[100];
 snprintf(aBuffer, sizeof(aBuffer), "%s%s%s", CYELLOW, text_info, RESET);
```

**Edit:** Please keep in mind, that `aBuffer` in the above example may be to small (depending on the length of `text_info`). Depending on your application you can just increase the size of `100` or dynamically allocating the buffer.

Comment: Or: `snprintf(aBuffer, sizeof(aBuffer), CYELLOW "%s" RESET, text_info);`

Answer (score 1):

In the working code, this line

```
readline(CYELLOW text_info RESET);
```

is macro-expanded to

```
readline("\001\e[0;31m\002" "simple string" "\001\e[0m\002");
```

which in turn, after string literal combination ends up as

```
readline("\001\e[0;31m\002simple string\001\e[0m\002");
```

which contains a simple string literal. No operators are involved, but it still ends up as a single parameter to the function.

In contrast to that, this line

```
readline(CYELLOW text_info RESET);
```

is macro-expanded to

```
readline("\001\e[0;31m\002" text_info "\001\e[0m\002");
```

which is not subject to string literal combination and therefor ends up with three string expressions (i.e. not exclusively literal strings, one being a non-literal string, a pointer to chars) without any operator in between.

Also, there is no simple operator for string concatenation (cases outside of string literal combination).

So in order to give a single string parameter ("string" as in "C-compatible zero-terminated sequence of chars, maybe array), you will have to construct such a string and then use it as single parameter for the function.

As Weather Vane has proposed, `sprintf()` is probably the tool to do that.